# App is not listed in Focus filter Settings if we build using XCode 14.1

Tags: xcode, filter, focus, appintents

We have implemented the focus filter using the AppEntity param type, Our app is visible in focus filter settings if we build/run with XCode 14 or 14.0.1. But the same is not if we run using the latest XCode 14.1.

**Note:** Our code base has both Objective C and Swift and minimum support for iOS 11. Previously(with XCode 14), faced crash issues earlier iOS 16 devices as the AppIntents library was not loaded which is fixed by a workaround including the "AppIntents" framework as optional/weak under link binary with Libraries in build phases.

Our Foucs filter has only single parameter/variable. Tried with changing the parameter type to string then it is visible, Subtyp of AppEnum or AppEntity is not working as expected.